# itext7 PdfAConformanceException: Maximum array capacity is exceeded

Tags: c#, itext, pdf-generation, itext7, pdfa

I am converting a text file of approx. 16K lines into a PDF/A-1b file. I get the exception "PdfAConformanceException: Maximum array capacity is exceeded". The document is generated with no problems if it is a normal PDF rather than a PDF/A. It happens only generating a PDF/A. The normal PDF document is about 1150 pages long. Any hint on how to solve this? The exception is generated in the "Doc.Close()" call.
This is the code that I use:

```
        StreamReader str = new StreamReader(file_name);

        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(file_name.Replace(".txt", ".pdf"));
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfADocument(writer, PdfAConformanceLevel.PDF_A_1B, new PdfOutputIntent
("Custom", "", "https://www.color.org", "sRGB IEC61966-2.1", 
new FileStream(INTENT, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)));

        Document doc = new Document(pdf);
        pdf.SetTagged();
        //Fonts need to be embedded
        PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(FONT, PdfEncodings.WINANSI, true);
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
        p.SetFont(font);
        p.Add(str.ReadToEnd());
        doc.Add(p);
        doc.Close();
```

Thanks!

Comment: I would propose not putting the whole text file into a single paragraph.

Comment: Thanks fo rthe hint. However, I think it has to do with the tags. The immediate output window says: "Tag structure flushing failed: it might be corrupted.". And commenting out the `pdf.SetTagged();` command it works just fine. I am wondering why.

Comment: Most likely, when you add the single paragraph with so many lines, each line gets its own marked content ID. In the  document structure tree that paragraph is represented as a structure element with a kids array containing all those IDs. As a consequence that array is larger than allowed for PDF/A-1 profiles.